# What does notation like $A^1_0$ and $f^2_1$ mean?

Tags: number-theory, logic

My logic book uses these symbols to represent predicates and constants, respectively (with varying numbers in the bottom/top), but I don't really know what they mean.

Any help?

From the book:

"Officially we think of ourselves as working for each $k > 0$ with a fixed denumerable stock of $k$-place predicates:

$A^1_0$   $A^1_1$  $A^1_2$...

$A^2_0$   $A^2_1$  $A^2_2$ ...

$A^3_0$   $A^3_1$  $A^3_2$ ....

...

and with a fixed denumerable stock of constant:

$f^0_0$   $f^0_1$  $f^0_2$ ..."

Comment: @AndréNicolas I edited with some info. from the book, maybe it can help.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From the additional information supplied, it seems clear that the superscripts are the **arities** of the predicate symbols and function symbols. The subscripts distinguish between symbols of the same arity.

A constant symbol can be thought of as a function symbol that denotes a function of $0$ variables. Hence the superscripts $0$ for the constant symbols.

An example of a predicate symbol of arity $1$ is a symbol intended to be interpreted as a *subset* of our domain $M$. A predicate symbol of arity $2$ is a symbol intended to be interpreted as a binary relation on $M$, that is, as a subset of $M\times M$.

A function symbol of arity $1$ is intended to be interpreted as a function from $M$ to $M$. A function symbol of arity $2$ is intended to be interpreted as a function from $M\times M$ to $M$, that is, as a function of $2$ variables.

But at the syntactic level, the arities determine only what is meant by a term, or an atomic formula. For example, if $P_1^2$ is a predicate symbol of arity $2$, and $s$ and $t$ are terms, then $P_1^2(s,t)$ is an atomic formula, but $P_1^2(s)$ is not a well-formed formula at all.

Comment: Can you elaborate on the subscript? I didn't quite get what you wrote.

Comment: The function symbols $f_0^2$ and $f_1^2$ are both function symbols of arity $2$, intended to be interpreted (in general) as *different* functions in $2$ variables, possibly addition and multiplication on the natural numbers.

Comment: @user1038665 - think at *variables*: they are "listed" as $x_0, x_1, x_2 ...$; the subscript is the *index* in their listing. The same with *function* symbols $f_0, f_1, f_2, ...$ and *predicate* symbols $A_0, A_1, A_2, ...$. In addition, *predicate* symbols have the *superscript* that indicate the "arity" : $<$ is a predicate symbol of arity $2$ (a binary *relation*) because we use it formally as $<(2,3)$, i.e. "informally" as $(2 < 3)$. A predicate of arity $1$ (unary) is "$Even(x)$". A predicate of arity $3$ is $Between(x,y,z)$, i.e. "the point $y$ lies between the points $x$ and $z$.